# How to combine the results of multiple columns from separate tables?

Tags: sql

I calculated the individual sum of one column from four separate tables and would like to combine them into one total sum. I have the correct output for each, I only need to add all sums.

```
SELECT SUM(fare_amount)
FROM `my-project-demo1-402016.yellowcabsnyc.jan2020`
WHERE passenger_count > 2
AND payment_type = 1 OR payment_type = 2
LIMIT 1000

SELECT SUM(fare_amount)
FROM `my-project-demo1-402016.yellowcabsnyc.feb2020`
WHERE passenger_count > 2
AND payment_type = 1 OR payment_type = 2
LIMIT 1000
```

I tried UNION ALL but it gave me back four separate rows with individual sums. I would like to see one combined total containing all four sums.

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Please add the one back that you actually use.

Answer (score 0):

Your both query resurn a scalar value which can be summed up quote nicely as subselects.

```
select 
(SELECT SUM(fare_amount)
FROM `my-project-demo1-402016.yellowcabsnyc.jan2020`
WHERE passenger_count > 2
AND payment_type = 1 OR payment_type = 2
LIMIT 1000) +

(SELECT SUM(fare_amount)
FROM `my-project-demo1-402016.yellowcabsnyc.feb2020`
WHERE passenger_count > 2
AND payment_type = 1 OR payment_type = 2
LIMIT 1000) as total_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

After using UNION ALL, you would get four separate rows, you just need to sum them. Add an overall SUM in order to get the combined sum. The query would be something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(partial_fare_amount) FROM
 (SELECT SUM(fare_amount) AS partial_fare_amount
 FROM `my-project-demo1-402016.yellowcabsnyc.jan2020`
 WHERE passenger_count > 2
 AND payment_type = 1 OR payment_type = 2
 LIMIT 1000
UNION ALL
 SELECT SUM(fare_amount) AS partial_fare_amount
 FROM `my-project-demo1-402016.yellowcabsnyc.feb2020`
 WHERE passenger_count > 2
 AND payment_type = 1 OR payment_type = 2
 LIMIT 1000)
AS combined_sum
```